# rangeOfString and NSNotFound result not what i expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm at bit of a loss here, I'm obviously doing something wrong and haven't grasped the way rangeOfString works.

I have a number of textfields and on certain of them, the phone and fax ones, i want to only permit a small range of values 1234567890+-() to be entered

I'm trying to use  `textfield: shouldChangeCharactersInRange: replacementString:` to not return the characters if they fall outside the specified set of characters.

My method is below and below that is an example of the log .

The code for not returning a ';' works fine, as does the code making sure its only the phone and fax number fields that are  being tested.

however what happens is it doesn't matter what character i enter - a '1' or '2' a letter or symbol, i get the same result NSNotFound.

Any idea where i am going wrong ?

Cheers

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string isEqualToString:@";"]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if( ([textField.placeholder isEqualToString:self.locationFieldNames[phoneNumber]]) | ([textField.placeholder isEqualToString:self.locationFieldNames[faxNumber]])){

        NSString *includeString = @"1234567890-()+";

        if ([string rangeOfString:includeString].location == NSNotFound) {
            DLog(@"%@ is NSNOTFOUND", string);
            return NO;
        } else {
            DLog(@"%@ is !NSNOTFOUND", string);
            return YES;
        }
    }
    DLog(@"got here");

    return YES;
}
```

and example from the log

```
2013-11-12 12:59:19.832 SplashDL[4138:70b] -[DiveFacilityDetailViewController textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:] 1 is NSNOTFOUND

2013-11-12 12:59:24.556 SplashDL[4138:70b] -[DiveFacilityDetailViewController textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:] q is NSNOTFOUND

2013-11-12 12:59:26.806 SplashDL[4138:70b] -[DiveFacilityDetailViewController textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:] ! is NSNOTFOUND
```

Comment: Why are you using the `placeholder`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: check the `||` in `if` condition

Comment: @preetam has a point.  Generally one should use `||` rather than `|` (and `&&` rather than `&`) in compound `if` statements, reserving the single characters for bit manipulation.  The single character version will work in this case, but can bite you in other situations.

Comment: @trojanfoe - the textfields are on a uitableview. there are 10 possible fields - only on 2 of which, phone number and fax number, i wish to restrict text entry to being that string of characters. I have the textfield and as the placeholders are unique for each of the textfields it seems like a decent way to decided which field has caused the method to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made misstake in following line of code:

```
if ([string rangeOfString:includeString].location == NSNotFound)
```

Change it to following:

```
if ([includeString rangeOfString:string].location == NSNotFound)
```

Also note that user may not only type text but he can also copy/paste it from somewhere. So the length of string may be greater than 1.

Comment: Is there any reason for downvoting? Have I written something wrong?

Comment: I dont know who did that - its not me - The only reason i haven't already clicked it as the right answer is that i won't let me for another few minutes. Spot on . Thank you so much for your help. Will mark as correct answer in just a moment

Comment: This question is not addressed to you, but to downvoter, or any person that sees the mistake in my answer.

Comment: yes, your answer is wrong and does not solve the problem. and return same results. look into mine.

Comment: @hasan have you tried it? I think that you don't understand the question.

Comment: Ah @hasan states (in a roundabout way) is that `rangeOfString` will look for the occurrence of that complete string (not any character within it).  You need to create a character set and use `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` instead.

Comment: @trojanfoe looks like 'string' always include one character. therefore, my concern is not valid. can't reverse my vote. 8 minutes passed. sorry for that. maybe if someone suggest an edit I can reverse it.